# dokku How to obtain internal-ip of a running container

Tags: docker, shell, nginx, dokku

I am trying to find the best way to obtain the internal ip of a running container in order to use it in my modified `nginx.conf` using `nginx.conf.sigil` for nginx reverse proxy. The `Procfile` contains multiple entries and one of which is the container which I need to obtain its internal-ip.

How to do that in dokku or nginx? I tried using the DNS name but it is not resolvable on the host.

Comment: The container-private IP address is an implementation detail that can't be used in most contexts, including directly from the host on non-Linux hosts.  You should be able to connect (or `proxy_pass`) to `localhost` and a `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` published port.

Comment: why is getting the ip an internal detail?the context is a rabbitmq service which is custom built and require routing via the same `nginx` config which is using a different `location`. I would think there are plenty of contexts to be able to do that. I would say dokku require some exposed variables which hold those IPs and make them available for us in `nginx` config. I noticed those IPs are already there in `dokku` home directory as plain text files. This in my opinion should be no different than the exposed `WEB_LISTENERS` variable which is available. it is more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: If both parts are running in containers, and they're on the same network, the containers' names can be used as host names without needing the IP address.  See for example [Use user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) in the Docker documentation.  If one part is outside a container then it can use `localhost` and a `docker run -p` published port.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand that. But my question is not about using exposed ports on the host, I prefer to avoid doing that altogether. If you check how `nginx.conf.sigil`  used by dokku works and run `dokku nginx:show-config <app>` it will show you that the internal ip is used as the upstream servers not `localhost` ports. check also that `$DOKKU_HOME/app/` on the host actually contains text files with container internal IPs `<IP>.servicename` `<Port>.servicename` which I simply `cat` in my nginx config but I think its not the best solution

Comment: where would you actually do `docker run -p` where dokku is managing docker itself and that would cause config be overridden on every deploys. if dokku doesnt provide a way to expose the port then i wouldnt touch `docker` commands. I refer to containers managed by dokku only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to be honest i think the question is pretty clear! there is an answer to it now in github https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/4749